# How to list php zvals without symbols pointing to it?

Tags: php, memory, memory-leaks

Following the example on [php reference counting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php), I created the situation shown at the bottom of this page: Two `zval` objects without a symbol pointing to that structure.

If I understand this article correctly, the structure still exists somewhere and consumes memory, but it is 'detached' from the rest of php. A memory leak.

Is there any way in PHP 5.2.10 to find such structures within a PHP code? I am able to use `xdebug`, but it might be very hard to use additional third-party software to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 5.3 PHP has a garbage collector which will care about that. You can follow it's description in the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php)

Comment: I changed the question. I need to find memory leaks in a PHP 5.2.10 code. Garbege collection was introduced with version 5.3. I cannot use version 5.3, I have to find the memory leaks in version 5.2 code.

Comment: May I ask why? Especially why on PHP5.2?

Comment: You may ask. It is an embedded, strongly modified gentoo Linux system. Even if I might get PHP 5.3 to work on this system, other systems sill only run with PHP version 5.2. I have to FIND the memory leaks and fix the code.

Comment: No, as this if for version 5.3 as it seems.

Comment: You are right, srry. Why is gc collecting so imortant? Normally the life cycle of a PHP (web) script is very short. If the code is well written it should not need to be garbage collected (normally even if it wasn't well written)

Comment: For a deamon running over days it gets very important. And for the code quality: You cannot imagine how bad.

Comment: Why do you code a PHP  daemon for an embedded system? I would code the daemon in C. If you need, you might let the daemon call php scripts on certain "events".

Comment: Also need to say, that producing that "leaks" is still up to the programmer. You can code in PHP5.2 which does not lead to unused variables. (I've coded at least one production daemon in PHP which never lead  to memory problems. However, there might appear problems even the experiencest programmer might not have expected, I admit that)

Comment: Please - I neither can explain the history of this product nor can I reimplement it with all the many shortsights. If you can answer my question I would be very grateful. If you cannot answer my question, please say so. Thanks